# Laravel, is it possible to break if statement inside foreach?

Tags: php, laravel

I need to break **if** statement inside **foreach** once the the **if** condition is true. Is it possible to break the **if** statement without breaking the **foreach**?

Below shows the codes that I was currently using now. But if I do this, it break the foreach too.

**Codes**

```
@foreach($furniture as $fur)
{
  //do something
  @if($fur->broken == true)
    //do something
    <php break; ?>
  @endif
}
@endforeach
```

Comment: what about ```@break```? What version of Laravel?

Comment: i tried using @break but didnt work...im using laravel 5.4

Comment: take out your curly braces

Comment: opps...yeah it works now

Comment: but still does not solve the problem

Comment: It's unclear what you want to do.. `break` always breaks the loop. what you want to do inside `if`

Comment: i wanted to break the if statement inside the foreach loop only...after break the if statement, the if statement will no longer usable/executed/run, and the foreach loop will still continue...is it possible?

Comment: I think that is not possible for next iteration it would again run the if statement in order to achieve this you need to again wrap this if statement inside another if statement and maintain flag to run the if statement

Comment: you can't just break it , cause it's a loop and you wont be able to recognize when did you break it at the first place. give some more info or try another method

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would use a do while inside the foreach

```
foreach($furniture as $fur){
//do something
    do{
        if($fur->broken == true){
          //do something
           break;
        }
    }while(false);
}
```

The Do While evaluates the condition after the first iteration, in this case the loop ends after the first iteration (because the condition is false), but this gives us a structure we can break out of.

The other way to do this is to use a switch statement with an if in it.

```
foreach($furniture as $fur){
//do something
    switch(1){
        default:
           if($fur->broken == true){
            //do something
             break;
           }
    }
}
```

Also note to break out of the foreach you can do `break 2` instead of just `break`.

All that said, I would say just from a best practice standpoint this makes the code less readable and what you need could be done without it ( most likely ) but I would need more details to help with that.

**UPDATE**

IS this a template thing like ( Blade )? It's not clear in the question.  I don't use blade, but I've seen it, studied it some, so that makes sense with the `@` sign.  But as I took the time to type this I'll leave it here.

Of note the same could **probably** be done in blade by faking a loop ( loop 1 time ) inside the foreach, same principle as the do while.  Assuming it supports break levels. Something like this

```
 @foreach($furniture as $fur)
    //do something 
     @foreach($fake as $f)     
         @if($fur->broken == true)           
          //do something
             @break
         @endif
     @endforeach
  //do something else
@endforeach
 //where fake is like  $fake = [1];  single element, so one loop.
```

You could also do the extra loop inside or outside the if block, as your needs dictate.

I am also not sure if Blade supports `switch` most template engines don't, but it may be cleaner to use if it does.

Comment: I don't use blade, I write my own Template engines.  I'm building a new one that is a lexer/parser/tokenizer, just saying.  I also don't use Laravel for the same reason, I build my own framework.

Comment: And just before I get any crap, for rolling my own, when I built the system at my work Laravel 4 wasn't a thing, and I have just over 7 years PHP experience, so I kind of know what I am doing at this point. To be honest it has a CI 2.0 backbone, but it's highly modified ( for PDO, exceptions and auto loading mostly, but some routing upgrades too )

Answer (score 1):

Check the Laravel documentation: https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/blade

Example from documentation:

```
@foreach ($users as $user)
    @if ($user->type == 1)
        @continue
    @endif

    <li>{{ $user->name }}</li>

    @if ($user->number == 5)
        @break
    @endif
@endforeach
```

Comment: this still break the foreach

Answer (score 1):

if is not a loop structure, so you cannot "break out of it".

You can, however, break out of the foreach by simply calling break. In your example it has the desired effect:

```
foreach($furniture as $fur) {
//do something
if ($fur->broken == true) {
    //do something            


    // will leave the foreach loop and also the if statement
    break;
}
this_command_is_not_executed_after_a_match_is_found();
```

}

Answer (score 0):

use `continue` instead of `break`:

```
@foreach($furniture as $fur)
  //do something
  @if($fur->broken == true)
    //do something
    @continue
  @endif

@endforeach
```

Comment: it does not break the if statement..but break certain amount of foreach data